# GS013 error when executing Gnosis Safe transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have created the following transaction in the Gnosis Safe Service:
https://gnosis-safe.io/app/rin:0x62c1bC4236F7df56D7475a1B95463236e3d85947/transactions/queue

This was created using the SDK:

```
const safeTransaction = await safe.createTransaction({
        to: toAddress,
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(String(amount)).toString(),
        data: `0x${uuid.replace(/-/g, "")}`,
});

const safeTxHash = await safe.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
await safeService.proposeTransaction({
          safeAddress,
          safeTransaction,
          safeTxHash,
          senderAddress,
});
```

2/2 signers have confirmed the transaction in Gnosis Safe. When trying to execute the transaction I get the following error message:
*This transaction will most likely fail. To save gas costs, avoid creating the transaction.*

And when proceeding anyway, incl manually setting the gas limit, I get the `GS013` error: `Safe transaction failed when gasPrice and safeTxGas were 0`
Transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x2f0e6b7b0dbbc14d01c2927397fbf066ab0aaede6fcdee6acd333c6b82a1ee3d

Where do I make sure that gasPrice and safeTxGas aren't 0?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not the `safeTxGas` and `gasPrice`. If you would set these value, the internal Safe transaction would still fail.

Looking at your transaction I can see that you try to transfer `8000000000000000 WEI` which amounts to `0.008 ETH` but the Safe only has `0.002999 ETH`, therefore the transaction fails because of insufficient funds.

More information on the `safeTxGas` and `gasPrice` issue can be found [here](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/a6504a9afdeac186a8cdb29ad68b189523c80eda/docs/safe_tx_gas.md).